Transformation Matrix Definition
The textbook I am referencing is here
https://mml-book.github.io/book/mml-book.pdf
and the definition I am asking about is on page 51.
In definition 2.19, the mapping $\Phi$ takes us from $V \rightarrow W$. We can see the linear mapping 2.92 and how the mapping applied to a basis $B$ in $V$ is equal to linear combinations of a basis $C$ in $W$. We can turn the coefficients of the linear combinations from 2.92 into the transformation matrix $A_{\Phi}$.
The columns of $A_{\Phi}$ are the coordinate representation of $\Phi(B)$ w.r.t $C$. I think my confusion lies in the next example, where $A_{\Phi}$ can be applied to coordinates in $V$ to get coordinates in $W$, w.r.t to their bases.
Question 1.
$A_{\Phi}$ is the transformation matrix that can take you from $V \rightarrow W$ w.r.t to their ordered bases, but in 2.92 why is $A_{\Phi}$ being applied to the ordered base $C$ of $W$? Or is it so that the mapping of $\Phi(B)$ is the transformation matrix applied to $C$, and it is also true that you can apply the transformation matrix to coordinate vectors in $V$ w.r.t to $B$ to get coordinate vectors in $W$ w.r.t to $C$?
Question 2.
What is meant by w.r.t to a basis? Aren't all coordinate vectors a linear combination of any of the bases that may exist in a vector space? How can a coordinate vector belong to a specific basis? For example, in 2.92, why is $\textbf{x}$ w.r.t to $B$ rather than any other basis in $V$?
Question 3. Is it valid to ask what is the coordinate representation of $B$ w.r.t to $C$? As I understand, we know what the coordinate representation of $\Phi(B)$ w.r.t $C$, but not $B$. If so, what is the representation?


I don't know why you think $A_\Phi$ is being applied to the ordered basis $C$, so it's a little tricky to answer this question.  In 2.92, the transformation is applied to every element of the basis $B$ (of $V$) to get an element of $W$, expressed in the basis $C$. So basically if, say, $\Phi(1,0,0)_B = (0,2,4,3)_C$ then the first column of your transformation matrix is 0, 2, 4, 3.

Are you familiar with polar coordinates (as the simplest version of other coordinates in the plane)? The same point will have different coordinates in the two different bases; for instance the point $(0,4)$ in rectangular would be $(4,\pi/2)$ in polar (or $(4, 90°)$ if you're a degree person). Both represent the same location in the plane (four "blocks" north of the origin), but the numbers are different because the numbers mean different things. (Admittedly, polar coordinates don't necessarily fit the span-of-vectors idea behind linear algebra, but the concept would be the same for, say, a coordinate system based on a parallelogram that does fit.)

If $V$ and $W$ are the same space, then yes you could find relationships between $B$ and $C$ (e.g. the polar version above, where $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$ is a relationship between rectangular $(x,y)$ and polar $(r,\theta)$).  If not, then asking how to express a point in $V$ using a coordinate system of $W$ is not that meaningful.


